# Writing contents of NSMutableArray to plist file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

So theres a page in my app where a large textfield appears, and the user inputs text and hits the save button. When the save button is hit, an NSMutableArray called savedPosts, which is declared in the AppDelegate file, saves the text content of the textfield to this array. This saving code is being called from some other view controller, not the AppDelegate, even though the actual array is declared in the AppDelegate. I'm not sure if that's a bad idea, but that's still not the issue. Anyway, I want it so that every time the user hits the save button on a new or existing post, it adds another object to the array and saves that same object to the plist. What would be the best way to set up this whole thing-to save posts from a textfield to an array which saves it automatically to the plist. How do I make it add an object to the plist file every time it is added to the array. Where should the array be declared and allocated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure your posts are always written out whenever you add a new one, I would make a very simple class that deals with posts as a whole. You could initialize the class with some URL which would then read the old persisted data into an array and implement some `-appendPost:` type of method that dealt with adding a new post and persisting the data back to the URL. The app delegate could then simply manage an instance of this class pointing to the appropriate URL. You could make it as complicated or simple as necessary.

A very simple implementation of such a class is attached below, which does only exactly what you've described in your question. It should be noted, however, that the code is for reference value only and obviously would not scale if the data set were to become very large.

This simple reference implementation would require iOS 4.0+ for the GCD calls and would need to be built with the LLVM 2.0+ compiler for the ivars-in-implementation. If you wanted to support an earlier version of iOS you could remove the GCD and synchronize some other way or block (not recommended). If you wanted to build with GCC-LLVM fronted instead of Clang, you could move the ivar decls to the interface.

```
// Posts.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Posts : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray* posts;

// Initialize with array at URL or create file
// if no array is there; if nil, posts contents
// are not persisted
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url;
- (void)appendPost:(NSString*)post;

@end

// Posts.m
#import "Posts.h"

@implementation Posts {
    // Persistent content URL
    NSURL* _url;

    // In-memory array
    NSMutableArray* _posts;

    // Used for synchronizing
    dispatch_queue_t _postQueue;
}

@dynamic posts;

- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithURL:nil];
}

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    if( (self = [super init]) ) {
        if( url ) {
            _url = [url copy];
            _posts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_url];
            if( !_posts ) {
                // You may not want to do this as it may later destroy whatever may have been at _url
                NSLog(@"Warning: Could not parse contents of url '%@': Creating new file", _url);
            }
        } else {
            _posts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        _postQueue = dispatch_queue_create("org.example.post_queue", 0);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_url release];
    [_posts release];
    dispatch_release(_postQueue);
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSArray*)posts
{
    __block NSArray* posts = nil;
    if( dispatch_get_current_queue() != _postQueue ) {
        dispatch_sync(_postQueue, ^{ posts = [_posts copy]; });
    } else {
        posts = [_posts copy];
    }
    return [posts autorelease];
}

- (void)appendPost:(NSString*)post
{
    if( [post length] == 0 ) return;

    dispatch_async(_postQueue, ^{
        [_posts appendObject:post];
        if( _url ) [_posts writeToURL:_url atomically:YES];
    });
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

`-[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:];` will do that for you as long as the contents of your array is made of plist objects, also there is nothing wrong in using  your application delegate as a central location for data to be shared with your whole app, thats what its for. Also if this data is small and persistent between executions of you application you may want to consider saving it to your user defaults through NSUserDefaults instead.